# Customized Error code to Java from pentaho Kettle

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

Is it possible to throw some customized error code to java from kettle.

Design:

KJB is invoking from java appliaction.

with the help of the below code we are deciding the job got success o r failure.

if(job.getErrors() < 1) {
             result=XXX;

```
     }
```

I supposed to throw some error code like '30' for filename missing ,'45' for input param missing' etc.

How to pass this code to java application from KJB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version is it? What does it mean kjb invoked ? Start job over rest service provided by carte server or you have embedded kettle engine into java application?

Comment: Can you provide some code snippet what have you done?

Comment: Pentaho 8.1 version. Pentaho job extension is kjb. Your are correct we are integrating the pentaho kettle into Java application.

Comment: JobMeta jobmeta=new JobMeta(pentahoJobLocation+Filename+plateWFDTestProtocolInstr.getFileDefinition().getReportTemplateName(),repository);
         Job job=new Job(repository, jobmeta);
    log.info("Starting pentaho file invokation.");
         job.start();
         job.waitUntilFinished();
         log.info("Pentaho file invokation done.");
   if(job.getErrors() < 1) {
    result=getFileResult(updatedRun, FilePath, fileName, Instr, updatedll.getlist().get(0), RunDTO);
      
   }

Comment: This is not trivial i believe. Job is kind of container for internal operations (transformations and jobs). There are many error might occurs, some are ignored and some are handled and some break execution. Even more, different type of errors can occur. Why not to use kettle provided steps to test file existence and validate input parameters?

Comment: As a good java practice, Runtime Exceptions must not be caught! :D

Answer (score 1):

As quick workaround, solution is not perfect. Add to job file existence and validation steps, log those errors and traverse logs after.

https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.1/Developer_Center/PDI/Embed#Obtain_Logging_Information